# Phonegap no internet alert pop up issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I search on the web and i get this script when tells the connection type when  an app opens.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

</script>
```

But what i wanted it to do is show the alert when there is no internet so i found a script which had a conditional statement but it failed to work

```
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE])
{
alert("Please check your internet connectivity and try again"); 
}
```

Please can someone show me the  way out and also i have a form that i submit and i want the form also to return to the same page if there's no internet onsubmit

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" action="http://mysite/login.php">
```

Comment: Isn't something delimited with `´` supposed to be a `char`, and not a `String`?

Comment: please show me where

Comment: Where you do `states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';`. Shouldn't be `states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = "Unknown connection";`?  And then, you should compare `String` with `.equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: Nevermind, I was confusing this with Java, instead of Javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning the `states[]` values to strings, I use `true/false` and knowing that `NONE` and `UNKOWN` are both indicators of no connection I set like this:

```
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
    states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
```

Then you can do:

```
if (states[networkState] === false) {
    //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a better option to hook on to the 'offline' event and then show your not connected message/alert when the event triggers. You could use this alongside the message you show when 'deviceready' event fires.

Make sure you have the `org.apache.cordova.network-information` plugin installed for any of this to work.

> The offline event fires when a previously connected device loses a
>   network connection so that an application can no longer access the
>   Internet. It relies on the same information as the Connection API, and
>   fires when the value of connection.type becomes NONE.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    // Handle the offline event
}
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md#offline

Comment: It is best to pair both solutions, as the use above will catch connection status on load and the event listener will catch dropped connections during app use.

Comment: I haven't tested to see if the 'offline' event is fired straight after 'deviceready' (would be nice if it did). You should check if it does (or not) and write your code accordingly. I would definitely use the 'offline' event in any case to catch dropped connections during app use. Let me know what you find :) It seems that from the docs you will need pair the solutions.