# Return False when no internet connection

Tags: jquery, cordova

I want a form to return false when there's no internet connection. I have the script that checks for the internet connection when the page loads and it works fine. But when the user submits and there is no internet, it bring out the alert right but still tries to submit and it brings out the default error webpage "the page could  not be found".

```
<form action="http://usersite.com/script.php"  method="post" name="form1" target="_parent" id="form1" onsubmit="checkConnection()">
```

Check for internet

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE])

    alert('No Internet Connection');
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: refer this, it might help you :
  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465524/phonegap-no-internet-alert-pop-up-issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465524/phonegap-no-internet-alert-pop-up-issue

Answer (score 1):

```
Define Enum

`var NetworkStatusEnum = {
 NO_INTERNET_DEVICE : {status:StatusCodes.NO_INTERNET_DEVICE,message:"No Internet connection on the device"},
 NETWORK_OK : {status:StatusCodes.NETWORK_FINE,message:"Network fine"}
}`

Write following method

`function isNetworkPresent()
{
      var response = {};

      var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
      var states = {};
      states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
      states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
      states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
      states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
      states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
      states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
      states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
      states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
      if (states[networkState]) {
          response = NetworkStatusEnum["NETWORK_OK"];

      } else {
          response = NetworkStatusEnum["NO_INTERNET_DEVICE"];
      }

         return response;
}`

Now wherever you want to check for internet call `isNetworkPresent` method

var networkResponse = isNetworkPresent();
if(networkResponse.status == StatusCodes.NETWORK_FINE)
{
    //Your code on internet present
}
else
{
    //Your code on internet not present
}
```